# WatIn SelectList().SelectByValue() return error Run script failed

Tags: c#, .net, watin

Hello i have some project that i build with WatIn i use methods like

```
  MainFrame.SelectList(Find.ById("mes1")).SelectByValue("12");
  browser.TextField(Find.ById("line")).TypeText("Vova");
```

And i getting  Error:

**Run script failed**

```
 using (var browser = new IE("https://test.html"))
            {
                   try
                    {
                        attempt = 50;
                        linkExist = browser.TextField(Find.ById("linea")).Exists;
                        while (!linkExist && attempt > 0)
                        {
                            Thread.Sleep(250);
                            linkExist = browser.TextField(Find.ById("lon")).Exists;
                            attempt--;
                         }
                        if (linkExist)
                        {

               browser.TextField(Find.ById("login")).TypeText(strUser);
               browser.TextField(Find.ById("pin")).TypeText(strPassword);//Run script failed
               browser.SelectList(Find.ById("mes1")).SelectByValue("12");//Run script failed
               browser.Button(Find.ByName("En")).Click();
               browser.WaitForComplete();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        successful = false;

                    }
}
```

i put only part of my code because code is working,but only in win7, but when i trying to run it on win2008 i gettin Error:

**Run script failed**

This error i see when i use SelectByValue or TypeText.

I checked all setting in my IE and the setting in windows 2008 R2 all setting and version are the same.

I think there are some setting in windows 2008 R2 that bloking my methods.

Do any one know how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution.There are Update of IE that released a month ago that conflict with WatIn methods, after removing it i resolve this problem.

The name of Update is :

> **security update for internet explorer 11 KB3008923**

Comment: I am still facing the issue with Windows Server 2008 R2. I tried to remove the update but still same error. Anything else you have done? I also read that you do not have to uninstall KB3008923 but to fix the problems because of this update you need to install other security update KB3025390 but I have no success. Still WatiN getting same error.

Comment: You need to do restart to you pc/server after you remove it,and check after restart if this update is still there.There are some servers that do auto update after you restart your server.This hapend to me,but after i turn off al auto updates all start to work.

Comment: Hmm that seems to be the issue, after restart everything got installed again. I have no control on updates as it is managed by InfoTech(IT) Dept of the company. Thanks for your info. We have informed IT about this.